# Aspcompat in ASPX Page

Tags: .net, com, sta, mta

In my aspx pages, I call a COM component that uses STA. So I use aspcompat=true parameter, but I want to understand the logic. What does it exactly do? As far as I know, in STA, it is **assumed** to be called only by one thread. So I should provide the thread safety myself.

If that's right, where does aspcompat parameter provide the thread safety? On the whole page, or just the point where I access the STA component?

Comment: did you get final solution? not marked answer

Answer (score 2):

> When using single-threaded apartment (STA) COM components, such as
>   components developed using Visual Basic, from an ASP.NET page, you
>   must include the compatibility attribute **AspCompat=true** in an

```
<%@ Page>
```

> tag on the ASP.NET page
>
> The AspCompat attribute forces the page to execute in STA mode
>
> ASP.NET by default uses MTA (multi-threaded apartment) threads
>
> When building ASP.NET applications that interface with old school COM
>   objects like those created with VB6 or Visual FoxPro (MTDLL), it's
>   extremely important that the threads that are serving requests use
>   Single Threaded Apartment Threading. STA is a COM built-in technology
>   that allows essentially single threaded components to operate reliably
>   in a multi-threaded environment. STA's guarantee that COM objects
>   instantiated on a specific thread stay on that specific thread and any
>   access to a COM object from another thread automatically marshals that
>   thread to the STA thread. The end effect is that you can have multiple
>   threads, but a COM object instance lives on a fixed never changing
>   thread.
>
> ASP.NET by default uses MTA (multi-threaded apartment) threads which
>   are truly free spinning threads that pay no heed to COM object
>   marshaling. This is vastly more efficient than STA threading which has
>   a bit of overhead in determining whether it's OK to run code on a
>   given thread or whether some sort of thread/COM marshaling needs to
>   occur. MTA COM components can be very efficient, but STA COM
>   components in a multi-threaded environment always tend to have a fair
>   amount of overhead.

**STA in ASP.NET**

> Support for STA threading in the ASP.NET framework is fairly limited.
>   Specifically only the original ASP.NET WebForms technology supports
>   STA threading directly via its STA Page Handler implementation or what
>   you might know as ASPCOMPAT mode. For WebForms running STA components
>   is as easy as specifying the ASPCOMPAT attribute in the @Page tag:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AspCompat="true" %>
```

> which runs the page in STA mode. Removing it runs in MTA mode. Simple.

**STA for non supporting ASP.NET Technologies**

> only WebForms supports STA natively

- ASP.NET HttpHandlers
- ASMX Web Services
- ASP.NET MVC
- WCF Web Services
- ASP.NET Web API

STA components are a  pain in the ass. I feel your pain :-)

Good reference:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications#STAfornonsupportingASP.NETTechnologies

Answer (score 1):

This directive causes ASP.NET to provide access to ASP-intrinsic objects and changes the thread pool to MTA.

For more details checkout [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk9h2kb.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a quote taken from; [Pro .NET Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430244585)

> AsP.nET executes pages on MTA threads by default. If you call sTA
>   objects, they undergo marshaling. If you predominantly call sTA
>   objects, this will degrade performance. you can remedy this by marking
>   pages with the  ASPCOMPAT attribute, as follows:
>
> ```
> <%@Page Language = "vb" AspCompat = "true" %>
> ```
>
> note that page constructors still executes in an MTA thread, so defer
>   creating sTA objects to  Page_Load and Page_Init events.